# How do I give 'space' or 'new line' between two radiobuttons while converting from picklist?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am just converting a picklist into the radiobuttons but there is no space or new line method between the values.Is there any way or method??

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!gaObj.No_of_Ticketed_Events__c}">
    <apex:selectoptions value="{!Radio}"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
```

---

```
public List<SelectOption> getRadio(){
    Schema.sObjectType sobject_type = gaObj.getSObjectType();
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sobject_describe = sobject_type.getDescribe();

    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> field_map = sobject_describe.fields.getMap();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pick_list_values = field_map.get('No_of_Ticketed_Events__c').getDescribe().getPickListValues();
    List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();
    for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : pick_list_values) {
        options.add(new selectOption(a.getLabel(), a.getValue()));
    }
    return options;
}
```

Comment: can you share your code what you did so far

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is quite simple if I understand you correctly - you want the values to go down the page? If so, define your radioButtons like so:

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!gaObj.No_of_Ticketed_Events__c}" layout="pageDirection">
```

This way they will render vertically, not horizontally.